# Hyperlinking merge tags

Tags: html, email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am attempting to use href to create a hyperlink with a unique URL with mailchimps merge tags, but I am having trouble

`<a href="*|CallBackURL|*" target="_blank">Click Here</a>`

But any tweaks I make to get this to work either result in it printing the entire URL and click here or it just prints Click here but the link is broken.

Can anyone point me the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is now working using the following line

```
<a href="{{url" "*|callbackurl|*"}}="" target="_blank">
```